# Eclipse environment doesn't see LG VS950 phone

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

I have read and tried everything I could find, though a lot of answers are old. I'm developing on Windows Vista. (I know, I know...) I've tried re-installing drivers, setting the USB mode to "charge only", turning "USB Debugging" on, manually shutting down and restarted the adb server, re-booting the PC and phone, on and on... All file sharing and updating utilities work properly. It's just Eclipse that won't talk. The phone is running 4.0.4. So 4.0.3 is the closest the SDK has. I can't post an image yet. But the "Choose a running Android device" dialog box never shows my device. The list of devices is always empty.

Comment: What about if you run adb devices? Does that show the phone? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#devicestatus

Comment: Does device manager (computer>device manager) shows your device? Seems like you had checked everything. Did you try a different usb cable and a different usb port? Just in case...

Comment: As raydowe said, try to use the adb command. Open the console (cmd command) and enter `adb devices`. Probably you have to change the directory to the platforms-tools directory of your Android SDK first. If ADB will not list your device, its defintely a driver issue. Open the windows device manager and check if their are any driver issues or unknown devices.

Comment: Thanks, guys. ADB does not show the device and I'm using the device driver from the LG web site for this specific VS950 phone. Should I be using some other driver? When I'm NOT in USB debugging mode I can do file transfers to/from the device and it appears in the "computer" window with all the other storage devices. Weird, huh? It's a new phone. Maybe they're having teething problems...